# Check strucutre of fieldsymbol

Tags: abap

I am having a fieldsymbol with type = data
`FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_it_orignal> TYPE data.`

Then I fill dynamically fill the field symbol`<fs_it_orignal> = some_values.`

this `some_value` can be either of structure A B or C .

I was looking for the best way to check where the `<fs_it_orignal>` is of structure A B or C.

Comment: Do you have a certain set of types or could it be anything in your dictionary?

Comment: "Fill" is not precise enough. With =, you assign values, but for a field-symbol to work, you need to ASSIGN a target variable first, and that's what determines the underlying structure. So please, don't just post incomplete fragments, but a complete example that demonstrates the actual issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just after knowing if the field symbol is of a certain type, you can do this by comparing the name of structure:

```
field-symbols: <fs_it_orignal> type any.

"-- Code here to assign your FS to something 

case replace( val   = cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_data( <fs_it_orignal> )->absolute_name
              regex = '\\TYPE='   with = '' ).
  when 'Z_STRUCT_A'.
    "-- Do what ever
  when 'Z_STRUCT_B'.
    "-- Do what ever
  when 'Z_STRUCT_C'.
    "-- Do what ever
endcase.
```